# Calculate the input resistance of the circuit with Miller's Theorem

Tags: input-impedance, miller-integrator

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 176.

Calculate the input resistance of the circuit with Miller's Theorem.

[image: hi]

In order to calculate the gain.

[image]

The current \$I_D\$  is 0 when doing small signal analysis, so we will have the following equation.

$$\frac{V_{out} - V_{in}} {r_o} - V_{in} (g_m + g_{mb}) = 0$$

$$A_v = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} =  (g_m + g_{mb}) r_o + 1$$

There is two resistor from Miller's therorem.

$$Z_X = \frac{r_o} {1 - A_v} = \frac{r_o} {1 - [(g_m + g_{mb}) r_o + 1]} = \frac{r_o} {-(g_m + g_{mb}) r_o}$$

$$Z_Y = \frac{r_o} {1 - 1/A_v} = \frac{r_o} {1 - 1/[(g_m + g_{mb}) r_o + 1]} = \frac{(g_m + g_{mb}) r_o + 1} {g_m + g_{mb}}$$

However, the book said

$$R_{in} = \frac{r_o} {1 - [(g_m + g_{mb}) r_o + 1]} \parallel \frac{1} {g_m + g_{mb}}$$

Where does this \$\mbox{$\Huge \frac{1}{g_m + g_{mb}} $}\$ come from?

Comment: If you look at the input node, there are two branches in parallel, the part you asked is the input impedance looking into the (ideal without CLM) transistor with the other part removed. 
https://player.slideplayer.com/80/13408131/slides/slide_9.jpg

Comment: @internet What is CLM?

Comment: Channel length modulation.

Comment: @internet Do you mean \$r_o\$ should be removed because channel length modulation is omitted?

Comment: What you did so far was to calculate the Zx (one path) but in this circuit, for the input node, we have two paths for the current to flow. One via ro/(1 - AV) (the one you calculated) and the second one (second path) is into the source terminal. Where is the second path input resistance? You haven't found it yet. And this is why you do not have 1/(gm + gmb).

Comment: @G36 I have no idea what you mean second path input resistance. Could you please draw a diagram for this second path?

Comment: You are studying a lot of this topic. So by now, it should be obvious to you Rin looking into the source terminal is 1/(gm + gmb) without the need to do any calculations. Page 53  -- > Example 3.5

Comment: @G36 It's easy to understand Page 53 -- > Example 3.5. But the schematics are different. In this one, it's current source \$I_1\$ in the drain, but it is \$Z_L\$ for Page 53 -- > Example 3.5.

Comment: I do not see any difference. I1 is an open circuit in small-signal analysis.  And ZL = ro/(1+1/Av).